# Como funcionan los Trailing commas en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Cuando se utilzan métodos/funciones en JavaScript, como en otros lenguajes de programación le podemos pasar parametros

**EJEMPLO**

```
function saludar(name){
   console.log("Hola: "+name)
}
```

Aquí mandamos llamar a la función

```
saludar("SO en español")
```

El resultado será

```
"Hola SO en español"
```

**EJEMPLO 2**

```
function hi(name, email, ){
  console.log(name+email)
}
```

> Al momento de llamar la función, como en la siguiente linea, daría
>   error pues con la coma que esta de mas marcaría error al estar
>   esperando un marámetro extra

```
hi("alfa", "mail@mail.com")
```

**LA EXCEPCIÓN A LA REGLA**

Aunque el error ocurre para la funciones, para el caso de los arreglos ha estado permitido el uso de comas extra

**EJEMPLO**

```
let datos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 54,];

console.log(datos);
```

¿Cómo tratan esto los **trailing commas**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cómo funciona?

A partir del nuevo estándar propuesto *se ignoran* en la declaración de parámetros de funciones, ya otros estándares hicieron lo mismo para objetos (ES5) y arrays.

### Para qué sirve?

Unifica el formateo del código y facilita la revisión y los diffs.

Ejemplo de código original sin usar trailing:

```
function laSuperFuntion(
  param1,
  param2
) {
   return ( param1 +  param2);
}
```

Agregamos la opción de restar:

```
function laSuperFuntion(
  param1,
  param2,
  param3
) {
   return 'restar'!=param3?(param1 + param2):(param1 - param2);
}
```

Un control de versiones dirá:

```
function laSuperFuntion(
  param1,
  param2,  // <- modificado
  param3   // <- nuevo
) {
   return 'restar'!=param3?(param1 + param2):(param1 - param2);  // <- modificado
}
```

Si en cambio tenemos la posibilidad de usar trailing commas en las function...

Ejemplo código original con trailing:

```
function laSuperFuntion(
  param1,
  param2,
) {
   return ( param1 +  param2);
}
```

Agregamos la opción de restar:

```
function laSuperFuntion(
  param1,
  param2,
  param3
) {
   return 'restar'!=param3?(param1 + param2):(param1 - param2);
}
```

Un control de versiones dirá algo mas cercano a lo que sucedió:

(se agregó un parámetro y se modifico el resultado)

```
function laSuperFuntion(
  param1,
  param2,
  param3   // <- nuevo
) {
   return 'restar'!=param3?(param1 + param2):(param1 - param2);  // <- modificado
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript ha incluido este toque un tanto permisivo para **no considerar como error una coma de mas** al pasar parámetros en una función del modo siguiente

**EJEMPLO 1**

```
let saludo = (name, ) => {
  console.log(name)
}

saludo("alfredo")
```

En el ejemplo anterior en una arrow function asociada a una variable, del modo **por expresión** también funcionará

**EJEMPLO 2**

```
let saludo = function(name, ){
  console.log(name)
}

saludo("alfa")
```

A nivel de una función por expresión, es decir una función anónima asignada a una variable

**EJEMPLO 3**

```
function saludo(name, ){
  console.log(name)
}

saludo("alfa")
```

A nivel de una función por declaración es decir una función que tiene un nombre directo asignado

EN TODOS LOS CASOS ANTERIORES FUNCIONARÁ

Comment: No me queda claro una cosa: Hablas de *JavaScript en su motor desde la versión ES7*... No hay un motor de Javascript único, cada navegador tiene uno. ¿Es parte de la especificación estándar ECMAScript?

Comment: tienes razón @PabloLozano me exprese mal, corregiré

Comment: Por cierto, siendo *muy pedante*, creo que lo de las comas se añadió en ES2017 que es ES8

Comment: no eres pedante, agradezco la aportación y ayuda para clarificar en que momento se incluyo muchas gracias @PabloLozano